# Seiberg-Witten theory and its physical interpretation

Tags: supersymmetry, seiberg-witten-theory

I have been working on [Seiberg-Witten theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg%E2%80%93Witten_theory) (well, I am now familiar with its computation),
but I do not know the physical concept of this theory.

For example, I know from the duality of electro-magnetic field, the variable  $(\begin{array}& a \\
a_D
\end{array})$ and its relation comes out.

As far as I know, these variables are parameters of low effective action for $N=2$ IR action, $i.e$ parameters of pre-potential. $F$

And from the duality relation of $a$ and $a_D$ ($F$ and $F_D$) there are some relation like
\begin{align}
&\tau= \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial a^2}, \quad \tau_D = \frac{\partial^2 F_D}{\partial a_D^2}  \\
& a_D = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a}, \quad a = - \frac{\partial F_D}{\partial a_D}
\end{align}
and eventually obtain
\begin{align}
\tau_D = -\frac{1}{\tau}
\end{align}
which seemingly interested with dual gauge coupling and original coupling is kind of relation as strong-weak duality.

Take further, using the seiberg witten curve $\lambda$
\begin{align}
a= \oint_{\gamma_1} \lambda, \quad a_D = \oint_{\gamma_2} \lambda
\end{align}
From this the mass spectrum of BPS particle
\begin{align}
M = n a + m a_D
\end{align}
which seemingly related with in $M$ theory picture's of n M2 brane and m M5 branes.

---

What is the physical interpretation of $a, a_D, \tau, \tau_D$ in Seiberg-Witten theory? Where do we apply this theory geometrically?

Comment: Asking for "any comment on Seiberg-Witten theory" is a bit broad. Can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I mean its physical interpretation or physical application. $i.e$ role of brane picture, relation to topological string theory and so on.